# Hosting for Java EE 7 Restful Webservice MySQL database

Tags: hosting, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

I have developed Restful Web service using Java EE 7, Netbeans 7.3.1 and MySQL database on GlassFish 4.0 webserver.

Now I am looking to host/deploy it on online server. I have searched for hosting provider for Java EE 7 with MySQL database on GlassFish 4.0 but could not able to find any. The one which I find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16523107/where-to-host-a-restful-web-service-in-java-in-shared-hosting-solutions) is [openshift](https://www.openshift.com/developers/java) which support Java EE 6 only at the moment.

What are my options? Is there any Hosting provider available to meet above requirements?

I am not sure, if i can use Google app engine or Amazon to host my above web services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenShift are good but expensive because they provide many services which you don't necessarily need (if you do - it's worth it!). You can use Rackspace - [they support Java 7](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/migrating-a-java-web-application-from-amazon-web-services). Further, I know you can use Amazon too - but I haven't done it myself - do some Googling to find out how.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudbees.com support java ee7. 5 free apps. Also they have an option to deploy on glass fish 4 through their click start option